# When following 302 redirect after domain forward, subsequent get requested back to original domain, causing a loop

Tags: http, dns, paw-app

First request to http://example.com:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/2.3.3 (Macintosh; OS X/10.11.4) GCDHTTPRequest
```

At this point, DNS forwards the request via 302 to https://www.example.com. (note protocol change)

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://www.example.com
```

At which point Paw makes the following request (and it is https at this point):

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
```

And gets this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Cowboy
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: Express
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Location: /verify-age
```

Here's where things get funny. That Location without hostname info actually makes the next request to the *original* hostname and protocol!! (now back to http for this request?!):

```
GET /verify-age HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

Which gets intercepted by the DNS server which responds with a 302 of course:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://www.example.com
```

Back to the right protocol and url, but of course the loop goes back to the 302 redirect to /verify-age, which switches back to the original protocol and hostname! And we're stuck in this loop. What weird is that Chrome doesn't follow this loop, but Paw does. So who's being bad here? DNS? Paw? Node? Chrome?

Comment: We've fixed this in Paw 2.3.4 https://luckymarmot.com/paw/updates/2.3.4 you can update in Paw menu > Check for updates…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is interesting. While  [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.30) required that that `Location` header field value consists of a single absolute URI (`Location = "Location" ":" absoluteURI`), this was modified in [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2) which relaxed the original constraint, allowing the use of relative URLs (`Location = URI-reference`), reffering to [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5) for the location value calculation.

In Section 5.1 RFC3986 explicitly states:

> Note that if the retrieval was the result of a redirected request,
> the last URI used (i.e., the URI that resulted in the actual retrieval
> of the representation) is the base URI.

So my guess is that browser which makes the next request to the original hostname is wrong here.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** this bug has been fixed in [Paw 2.3.4](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/updates/2.3.4)

---

I confirm that this is a bug from Paw, and I've been able to reproduce this myself. We're going to fix this in the next bugfix version of Paw that should come out within 10 days hopefully. Thanks for reporting this, and sorry for the inconvenience.